# Ensure free data transfer from S3 to EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

[Amazon's pricing documentation](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) says

> "Data Transfer OUT From Amazon S3 To Amazon EC2 in the Northern Virginia Region (is) $0.000 per GB"

Is there anything special I need to do to ensure that I don't get charged for transfers from S3 to EC2, assuming both are in the Northern Virginia Region? IE) Is executing a GET request from this EC2 instance to https://s3.amazonaws.com/{bucketName}/{resource} going to automatically get counted as 'free' without doing anything additional? Or is there a private IP address for S3 that I need to access in this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the request comes from within the same region, you're likely to be redirected to the right endpoint and not going to be charged. If you want to be 100% sure, however, you can choose the correct endpoint yourself:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region

This may be particularly useful if you use API and tools from 3rd parties, which sometimes use varying default endpoints, unless you override them explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your S3 buckets are in the **same region** as your EC2 machines, your data xfers are free. If you always deal with the same region, then you do not have to worry about the data xfer cost.

Data Transfer OUT From Amazon S3 To
Amazon EC2 in the **same region**   $0.000 per GB